# No search result is not poping up a message window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a search function in my software
when the search result is **zero**. Its not giving me any pop up windows or any message. How to deal with this situation
My code is as below.

I need any message to be pop up, the moment it shows no data from my table.

```
   private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
       {
            this.cncInfoTableAdapter.SearchFileName(this.cncDataSet1.CncInfo, textBox1.Text);
        }
       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No records Found " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The code of the `timer1_Tick` (??):

```
int count = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    count = cncInfoBindingSource.Count;
    label_status.Text = "Records Found: "+count.ToString();
    if (count < 2) {
        Next_btn.Visible = false;
        Previous_btn.Visible = false;
    } else {
        Next_btn.Visible = true;
        Previous_btn.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Advice please
Thanks

Comment: We need the details of `SearchFileName` are you sure you throw an exception if no results can be found?

Comment: @CommuSoft    `int count = 0;
                private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
              {
             count = cncInfoBindingSource.Count;
            label_status.Text = "Records Found: "+count.ToString();
            if (count < 2)
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = false;
                Previous_btn.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = true;
                Previous_btn.Visible = true;
            }
           }

Comment: `above is the code I did for search function`

Comment: that's `timer1_Tick` (I've updated your answer). The message box does not occur because `SearchFileName` never throws the exception.

Comment: ` int count = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count = cncInfoBindingSource.Count;
            label_status.Text = "Records Found: "+count.ToString();
            if (count < 2)
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = false;
                Previous_btn.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = true;
                Previous_btn.Visible = true;
            }
        }`

Comment: No: `timer1_Tick` has not (much) to do with it. In your method you call `this.cncInfoTableAdapter.SearchFileName`. We need to know what's behind that method. I'm convinced the method simple never throws an exception. A reference to the documentation is acceptable as well...

Comment: @CommuSoft Could you edit it and posit it to me please. As I am a beginner in this. this search itself took me a lot of time.

Comment: @CommuSoft I gave the above code in search button. Still its the same case. No message is poping  up